# How to convert a Multi AZ instance to Single DB instance in AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it even possible to convert a multi AZ rds instance to single DB instance in AWS RDS?
No clear documentation and when I try to modify the multi AZ instance, it has no option to switch from multi az to single az instance.

Yes the db instance have data in it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to migrate your entire db to a new rds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly [move from a non-Multi-AZ instance to a Multi-AZ instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZSingleStandby.html#Concepts.MultiAZ.Migrating), but it would appear that there is no option to revert to being a 'single' instance.

Therefore, you would need to:

- Create a **Snapshot** of the Multi-AZ instance
- Launch a new Amazon RDS database from the snapshot
- Change all references to the database to the new 'single-AZ' Database
- Delete the Multi-AZ database when you have confirmed it is not required

It is not possible to have two databases with the same 'name', hence the need to change references. If you *need* to maintain the same name, you could delete the Multi-AZ database after creating the Snapshot and then create the new 'single-AZ' database with the same name.

Comment: I wonder if the inability to go from Multi-to-single AZ is only for PostgreSQL? On a MariaDB instance, I was able to modify the instance to be Single-AZ. On the modify form, I just checked the radio button 'do not create a standby instance' under availability, and it worked. It took a few minutes to modify, but there was no downtime.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can move from Multi-AZ to single-AZ now.

- Click on "Modify" instance. Select "Do not create a standby instance".
- Click on continue & modify it. It should be done in 5-10 mins.

> **Single-AZ to Multi-AZ**, no downtime but slight performance impact.
> **Multi-AZ to Single-AZ**, no downtime, no performance impact

PS - Added the answer so that it can save someone else's time.

[image]

[image]